# Facebook locale and currency

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, locale, currency

The locale and currency field of the User Graph API object is Deprecated!
How do I can determine the locale of a person using my app?
I need this information for app localization
How do I can know about user currency for correct display of the products in my app?

Comment: Depending on your application you can use the locale information from the browser or the application (don't know if ios or android provide such information)

Comment: Or geolocation/ an IP-based location approximation service. Present the user with a sensible default based on that, and offer them to switch to other options manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can now find **user_currency** in the **payment_mobile_pricepoints** field.
Don't forget to add payment_mobile_pricepoints to your "/me" FB API request

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web canvas app, you can get current user locale from POST request, which facebook platform do each time when your app started. So you can find 2 fields: signed_request, fb_locale. It works only for current user.